# NumberFormatException: Infinite or NaN

Tags: java, fibonacci, numberformatexception

I have a method that takes n and returns nth Fibonacci number. Inside the method implementation I use `BigDecimal` to get the nth Fibonacci number then I use method `toBigInteger()` to get the number as a `BigInteger` object and that's surely because I am working with huge numbers in my application.

I keep getting correct results until I pass **1475** as an argument for my method. I get `NumberFormatException: Infinite or NaN` in this case without any clear reason for me.

**Could you please explain me why am I getting this exception?**

Here's my method:

```
BigInteger getFib(int n){
     double phi = (1 + Math.sqrt(5))/2;
     double squareRoot = (Math.sqrt(5)) + (1/2);
     BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(Math.floor(Math.pow(phi, n)/(squareRoot)));
     return bd.toBigInteger();
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `Math.pow(phi, n)` is too big(Infinity),double is unable to store it,use BigDecimal instead.

How about the flowing:

```
static BigInteger getFib(int n) {
    BigDecimal x1 = new BigDecimal((1 + Math.sqrt(5)) / 2);
    BigDecimal x2 = new BigDecimal((1 - Math.sqrt(5)) / 2);
    return x1.pow(n).subtract(x2.pow(n))
            .divide(new BigDecimal(Math.sqrt(5))).toBigInteger();
}
```

from the formula:[image]

**UPDATE:**
the above way is incorrect,because Math.sqrt(5) does not has enough precision as the comment said. I've tried to culculate sqrt(5) with more precision using Netown's method,and found out that `x1.pow(n).subtract(x2.pow(n)).divide(...)` is very time-consuming,it spended about 30 seconds for n = 200 in my computer.

I think the recursive way with a cache is mush faster:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    long start = System.nanoTime();
    System.out.println(fib(2000));
    long end = System.nanoTime();
    System.out.println("elapsed:"+ (TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS.toMillis(end - start)) + " ms");
}

private static Map<Integer, BigInteger> cache = new HashMap<Integer, BigInteger>();

public static BigInteger fib(int n) {
    BigInteger bi = cache.get(n);
    if (bi != null) {
        return bi;
    }
    if (n <= 1) {
        return BigInteger.valueOf(n);
    } else {
        bi = fib(n - 1).add(fib(n - 2));
        cache.put(n, bi);
        return bi;
    }
}
```

It spend 7 ms in my computer for n = 2000.

Comment: 80776376321566249506594310369598056472970340482296717528846843403451897402974064859772924316558310641200045712627734657615023748095728890842338729730058516953255187002299033438319847576705753443152494213260389820409161525095795264470887903665494432793647441708843372648309455220167976247625265489563686977653

Comment: I'm not sure this produces correct fibonacci numbers above 71, due to the limited precision of `Math.sqrt(5)`.  According to OEIS http://oeis.org/A000045/b000045.txt the 1475th fibonacci number is 80776376321562253452154706580907152472160058839390611448949567098441231253468434896849142844747379890769208411232896054029055178267612427002841980625179761093160192801001760246411376424603323375022055947591818021711030476170155984070706514302882384774850491778697586460466725335267737494971685815687040886025.

Comment: Yes ... getting an accurate value out of this formula is going to be exceedingly difficult.  1) BigDecimal numbers have fixed precision to the right of the decimal point.  2) You can't use `Math.sqrt(5)` ... it is not accurate enough.

Comment: Impressive. i tried loops but its too curmbersome then i gave recursion a short and as the number increased, it slowed down now back to this and all is good. caching improves speed

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is here:

```
BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(Math.floor(Math.pow(phi, n)/(squareRoot)));
```

the result of `Math.floor(Math.pow(phi, n)/(squareRoot))` is giving you either infinite or NaN.

According to the [BigDecimal javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) that constructor (`BigDecimal(double)`) could throw a `NumberFormatException` if you use a double with value infinite or NaN

Answer (score 1):

This is not cause of the INF's / NaN's but it is definitely wrong.  This ...

```
double squareRoot = (Math.sqrt(5)) + (1/2);
```

... is equivalent to this ...

```
double squareRoot = Math.sqrt(5));
```

... because `(1/2)` is an integer division, returning an integer value; i.e. zero.

---

In fact, I think the most likely explanation for the INF / NaN is that "phi<sup>1475</sup>" is too large to be represented as a `double`.  So the `pow` method is returning `INF` ... which is the way that "too large" is represented as a floating number in Java.

---

If you want to compute Fibonacci numbers this way, you need to use a representation that is capable of representing the really large numbers involved ... and represent them with sufficient accuracy.  The Java `double` type cannot do this.  And indeed, it is hard to do the computation using `BigDecimal` ... as the comments on the accepted answer demonstrate!

I'd recommend using the recurrence relation.  It is going to be much simpler ... and probably more efficient as well.

Comment: That's right that "phi1475" gives infinity. I could actually use BigDecimal instead and it works fine but there's still one problem. What's the equivalent to Math.floor in this case for BigDecimal?

Comment: Try `round` with a rounding mode of `FLOOR`.  But I thing that using the recurrence relation is likely to be much faster and more reliable.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a good idea to create `BigDecimal` with float or double because its again limit to the range of them
you must create a BigDecimal at first and do some operation with its functions like:

```
BigDecimal a;
BigDecimal b;
x1.pow(b);
```

Comment: BigDecimal does not have a pow method accepting another BigDecimal. In fact it only support power to integer (`int`) values.